# Is there an iphone app to check if the brightness of your computer monitor is too bright?

Tags: iphone, display, applications

I've been looking for an app to check if the brightness of my computer monitor is too high and is straining to my eyes.
Does such an app exist that measures brightness of a monitor using the camera perhaps?

Comment: Why does too bright stain your eyes - may eyes are strained if too dark

Comment: @Mark It's similar to staring at the sun or a lightbulb. Too much light makes your pupil constrict too much and strains your eye.

Comment: and too dark hurts mine - the suns many many times lighter than any artificial light

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, they can be pretty expensive, but apps made for professional designers and photographers can do this.  **DisplayMate** and  **Datacolor Spyder5Elite** are two often cited products.

On the free side, there's several dozen that use the iPhone camera, including **LuxCamera**, **Luxi**, and **LightMeter Free**, to measure light.  Although, YMMV with these free apps, they should be able to give you a semi-decent reading.

I use a free application named [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com) to automatically adjust the 'blue' light emitted by my monitor.  It works great and I would strongly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have used f.lux, but I found I turned it off so often that i just uninstalled it. The color of what I'm working on is important and I found f.lux would change my colors around. Do any of those apps tell you if the monitor needs to be adjusted?

Comment: I don't think they can tell you if it needs to be adjusted, they can just tell you what it is.  You'll need to make the determination on the adjustment.  I don't know of any app that would do that (not that the app doesn't exist, just that I'm not aware of any).